# JavaFX - Change color on slider thumb when clicking on a button

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I am pretty new to programming and working on a little program where i use a jfx slider to control my volume. I used CSS to change the color of the thumb. in the slider. But now i want to be able to click on my JFXToggleButton to switch theme of my program. So i want to be able to switch the color of the thumb from #8faeea to white.

The code i used in my css to set the color of thumb is:

```
.jfx-slider .thumb
{
    -fx-background-color: #8faeea;
}
```

The slider has id is sliderVolume.

I tryed different things in my code like:

sliderVolume.setStyle(".thumb -fx-background-color: white;");

But I am unsure how to implement the .thumb to make it work.

I used code like this lblCurrentSong.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;"); to change color on other labels and buttons in my program, which works fine, but again these are not modified in my css.

I used scene builder set up the GUI, if that has any relevance.

I tried to search forums, but couldn't find a solution that fitted my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a looked-up color:

```css
.jfx-slider {
    -thumb-color: #8faeea ;
}

.jfx-slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -thumb-color ;
}
```

and then in your Java code you can do

```
sliderVolume.setStyle("-thumb-color: white;");
```

Comment: Thanks alot James_D, for the quick response, the solution worked perfect!